# Python Pandas MultiIndexing: Duplicate rows and add differentiating information in new column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm a python beginner trying to duplicate existing rows, while adding differentiating information in a new column. Currently, my DataFrame looks like so:

```
Patient  Visit
      1     V1
      1     V2
      1     V3
      2     V1
      2     V2
```

I'd like to add a new column `Test` which for `V1` requires `Test 1`, but for `V2` and `V3` requires both `Test 1` and `Test 2`:

```
Patient  Visit    Test
      1     V1  Test 1
      1     V2  Test 1
      1     V2  Test 2
      1     V3  Test 1
      1     V3  Test 2
      2     V1  Test 1
      2     V2  Test 1
      2     V2  Test 2
```

I'd then further like to add a column `Sample` which adds an `A` and `B` sample for each test:

```
Patient  Visit    Test  Sample
      1     V1  Test 1       A
      1     V1  Test 1       B
      1     V2  Test 1       A
      1     V2  Test 1       B
      1     V2  Test 2       A
      1     V2  Test 2       B
...
      2     V2  Test 2       A
      2     V2  Test 2       B
```

How do I duplicate the rows while adding new information in the additional columns? Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can manually create your Visits-Test-Sample dataframe, then `merge` with Patients dataframe:

```
pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['V2','V3'],['Test 1', 'Test 2'],['A', 'B']], names=['Visit', 'Test', 'Sample'])\
  .union(pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['V1'],['Test 1'],['A','B']], names=['Visit', 'Test', 'Sample']))\
  .to_frame().reset_index(drop=True)\
  .merge(df, on='Visit')\
  .sort_values('Patient')
```

Output:

```
   Visit    Test Sample  Patient
0     V1  Test 1      A        1
2     V1  Test 1      B        1
4     V2  Test 1      A        1
6     V2  Test 1      B        1
8     V2  Test 2      A        1
10    V2  Test 2      B        1
12    V3  Test 1      A        1
13    V3  Test 1      B        1
14    V3  Test 2      A        1
15    V3  Test 2      B        1
1     V1  Test 1      A        2
3     V1  Test 1      B        2
5     V2  Test 1      A        2
7     V2  Test 1      B        2
9     V2  Test 2      A        2
11    V2  Test 2      B        2
```

Comment: @Oliver You're welcome. Happy coding.  Be safe and stay healthy.  Thanks, Shubnam for the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to present this step by step using explode:

Create DF:

```
      t = pd.DataFrame({'Patient': [1,1,1,2,2],
             'Visit': ['V1', 'V2', 'V3', 'V1', 'V2']})

       Patient  Visit
      0    1    V1
      1    1    V2
      2    1    V3
      3    2    V1
      4    2    V2
```

Add Test column:

```
    t['Test'] = t['Visit'].apply(lambda x: ['Test 1'] if x == 'V1' else ['Test 1', 'Test 2'])

     Patient    Visit   Test
   0    1         V1    [Test 1]
   1    1         V2    [Test 1, Test 2]
   2    1         V3    [Test 1, Test 2]
   3    2         V1    [Test 1]
   4    2         V2    [Test 1, Test 2]
```

Use explode to get each of the tests as its own row:

```
       t = t.explode('Test')    # Since this cannot be done inline you need to copy this to the original DF.

       Patient  Visit   Test
       0    1   V1  Test 1
       1    1   V2  Test 1
       1    1   V2  Test 2
       2    1   V3  Test 1
       2    1   V3  Test 2
       3    2   V1  Test 1
       4    2   V2  Test 1
       4    2   V2  Test 2
```

Do the same for the 'Sample' column:
Add 'Sample' Column:

```
      t['Sample'] = t['Test'].apply(lambda x: ['A', 'B'])
```

Explode 'Sample Column:

```
      t = t.explode('Sample')
```

Here is the final output:

```
         Patient    Visit   Test    Sample
       0    1   V1  Test 1  A
       0    1   V1  Test 1  B
       1    1   V2  Test 1  A
       1    1   V2  Test 1  B
       1    1   V2  Test 2  A
       1    1   V2  Test 2  B
       2    1   V3  Test 1  A
       2    1   V3  Test 1  B
       2    1   V3  Test 2  A
       2    1   V3  Test 2  B
       3    2   V1  Test 1  A
       3    2   V1  Test 1  B
       4    2   V2  Test 1  A
       4    2   V2  Test 1  B
       4    2   V2  Test 2  A
       4    2   V2  Test 2  B
```